# How do i know that which IVR key option was pressed by user via Twilio API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hint : As I know that parameter name for IVR option is 'Digit' used in `<Gather>` which is sent by Twilio `$_REQUEST` method.

I want to fetch this `$_REQUEST['Digits']` value if Twilio maintain this record?.

Comment: @Vadim Kotov are you able to understand my question?

Comment: Actually, no. It is unclear to me. Also, I'm not an expert in Twilio, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio will make a request with the ['Digits' parameter to the action URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) you specify. If there is no action URL, by default Twilio will POST to the current document. The digits are not stored anywhere on Twilio and not retrievable later.

There's a [tutorial on receiving user input from the keypad with Twilio in PHP here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-in-php).

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Thanks for leaving a great answer!

Comment: @reema Naqvi, could you please give us the API name which will resolve my problem

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, you can't get the input Digits from an API, they only come through the call live as parameters to the webhook. [Check out this tutorial for how to use the `Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-in-php).

Comment: @philnash I was asking that which twilio API can give me the Digit's value. And you already gave me your answer that "you can't get the input Digits from an API, they only come through the call live as parameters to the webhook"